# How do I split an array of text into 3 textboxes using Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I so far have created a randomizer in Virtual Basic 2010 that:

1. Takes people's names that the user imputed in form2 into an array (split by spaces).
2. Randomizes the array
3. Displays the array with a consecutive number and period behind it for each name that was imputed.

Here is the source code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim names() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim txt As String

    ' Put the names in an array. SaveTitle is all the text saved in Form2
    names = Split(My.Settings.SaveTitle, " ")

    ' Randomize the array.
    Randomize()
    For i = LBound(names) To UBound(names) - 1
        ' Pick a random entry.
        j = Int((UBound(names) - i + 1) * Rnd() + i)

        ' Swap the names.
        tmp = names(i)
        names(i) = names(j)
        names(j) = tmp
    Next i

    ' Display the results.
    For i = LBound(names) To UBound(names)
        txt = txt & vbCrLf & i + 1 & ". " & names(i)
    Next i
    txt = Mid$(txt, Len(vbCrLf) + 1)

    RichTextBox1.Text = txt
End Sub
```

Pay attention to the last bit. I want to take the variable txt and split it. Then I want to take the first 10 names and display them in RichTextBox1, take the next 10 names and display them in RichTextBox2, and display the last 10 names in RichTextBox3.

How can I do this?

Comment: and did you try re splitting the new array and print 1 to 10 on one box, 11 to 20 on another and so on?

Answer (score 1):

try this way.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim lstNames() As String
        Dim txt1, txt2, txt3 As String

        ' Put the names in an array. SaveTitle is all the text saved in Form2
        lstNames = Split(My.Settings.SaveTitle, " ")

        ' Randomize the array.
        Randomize()

        ' try this 
        For n As Integer = 0 To lstNames.Count - 1
            lstNames(n) = String.Format("{0}{1} ", lstNames(n), Rnd() + n)
        Next

        For n As Integer = 0 To lstNames.Count - 1
            If n < 10 Then
                txt1 += lstNames(n)
            End If

            If n > 9 And n < 20 Then
                txt2 += lstNames(n)
            End If

            If n > 19 And n < 30 Then
                txt2 += lstNames(n)
            End If

        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = txt1
        RichTextBox2.Text = txt2
        RichTextBox3.Text = txt3

    End Sub
```